# Why does the preview change when I click show layout decorations button in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, user-interface, frontend, show

I have designed the front end for my application it looks fine in the preview but when i click "show layout decorations" button the total preview is being disturbed! i am not able to get proper output.
can someone check this out? this is for my school project.[preview before pressinf "show layout decorations"[preview after clicking show layout decorations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk5mu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue has been solved in the new Android Studio update

Update your android studio to the latest version and it should work...

You can simply use the shortcut key to check for your version and know if you could update...

Simply tap **Shift** twice then in the small box...input **About** to check for version and **update** to update your ide to the latest version...this should work.

Cheers